# Keep nav list item selected when submenu is open

Tags: css, navigation

How do I change the CSS so that a main menu list item stays selected when clicked? I can change the background color on hover, but I'd really like the background color to change when clicked until I click on something else. My submenu displays on click, not hover, which is why hover does not work for me.

For example, on www.IBM.com, the style of the selected list item in the main menu changes when clicked, not just on hover.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="site-nav">
    <li class="first">
       <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="quick-more">
       <a class="drop-link">Support</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" style="display: block;">
       ......etc.
    <li>Community</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my CSS, I have the following:

```
.site-nav {
  background: #1f78c3;
  }
.site-nav .dropdown {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 }
.site-nav li a:hover{
 background: #fff;
 color: #1f78c3;
 }
```

I've also tried a:visited and a:target, but neither of those did the trick. Any idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @htmltroll and @Joel said, you'd need to use a little bit of JS(jQuery in my case) to achieve this, as CSS doesn't handle click events.

To make it a bit more modular, you could check to see if any .site-nav li has a nested ul, and then apply the 'active' class accordingly.

```
// any <li> that is a direct descendant of 'site-nav
var links = $('.site-nav').find('> li');

// bind the click event 
links.on('click', function() {

    var clkd = $(this);

    // if the <li> has a <ul> in it
    if(clkd.has('ul').length) {

        // and if that <li> doesn't have the 'active' class
        if(!clkd.hasClass('active')) {

            // Add the active class to the <li>
            clkd.addClass('active');

        } else {

            // if the dropdown was already open, remove class to close
            clkd.removeClass('active');

        }

    }

})
```

I threw together a quick fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/uXB2T/7/

Comment: That demonstration is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Almost there. I got it to work, except for one issue. When I clicked Support, the new background displayed with the dropdown (what I wanted to happen). However, when I clicked somewhere else on the page, the new background still displayed without the dropdown. When I clicked Support again, the new background disappeared and the dropdown displayed. How do I keep the new background consistent with the dropdown?

Comment: Think you could get your code up on jsfiddle so I can see whats going on?

Comment: Sure, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/uXB2T/8/. I haven't done that before, so let me know if it didn't work. The nav is working almost exactly how I want it to... I have two main list items that have submenus. Could the issue be from my submenus being 3 columns wide? In JSFiddle, if you click on Solutions and then click on Support, both submenus display. However, if you do the same thing on the live site, only one submenu displays but both Support and Solutions have the same background color. I very much appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a .selected to a link on different pages and target it with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried a:active as well. It works for one second. When I press the mouse it works, and then when i let go, it doesn't. Is there a way to keep the link active so that it works when I let go of the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

The method I would use is a javascript/jQuery approach.

Similar to what htmltroll said, create a class, such as `.selected`, that has all of the styles you'd like the active link to have. Then in javascript, add something like this:

```
$(your-links).click(function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("selected"))$(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Your syntax is a bit off.  You're missing a `)` to close the condition, and a set of curly brackets around what should happen if the condition is met.

Comment: I did miss the ) but the curly brackets are not necessary.